# Fast Load Matrices [Numpy/Java]

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, clojure

Python tries:

I have matrices ~(50000 * 100), and some more of 50*100, (50000*2). 
I saved them using numpy_compressed and it loads the matrix back in around 300ms. Saving this as Json (list-of-list)[Same as saving to str dump and using eval] takes around 700ms.

My main objective is to load matrices fast for a service which requires fast response. The actual matrix computation, once the matrices have been loaded in memory is ~2ms.

How can the numpy matrices be loaded fast ?
Is it faster in Java/ Clojure?

Comment: Please take a look to HDF5. This is a pretty standard way to store matrices in numerical applications. HDF5 is optimized for high-performance computing. AFAIK, It also support compression if needed. Json is a poor choice for storing matrices as it is not optimized for speed and store information in text (that usually take much more space/time).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the speed of (de-)serialization. In general, byte/raw serializers are potentially faster than text serialization like JSON. The actual performance will depend on your exact case, so if the performance is really critical, you should test it with different serializers.

This being said, [Transit](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-clj) is a good option for transferring data between applications that are written in different languages. On the other hand, a benchmark of Java serializers can be found at: https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki.